# bokeh - ValueError: Keyword argument sequences

Tags: pandas, bokeh, stacked-chart

Below is two sets of code. The first set of code works and gives the desired outcome. However, when i try to extend the size of the dataframe, as in the second set of code, with an additional column i get an error message.

The error message I get is below.

```
raise ValueError("Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must all be the same lengths. Got lengths: %r" % sorted(list(lengths)))

ValueError: Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must all be the same lengths. Got lengths: [3, 4]

raise ValueError("Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must all be the same lengths. Got lengths: %r" % sorted(list(lengths)))

ValueError: Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must all be the same lengths. Got lengths: [3, 4]
```

Code 1 which works

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral3

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['<£5000', '£100K to £250K'],
           '01/01/2014': [8,1],
           '01/01/2015': [8,2],
           '01/01/2016': [7,1]})


grouped = df.groupby('Category')['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016'].mean().round(0)

source = ColumnDataSource(grouped)
countries = source.data['Category'].tolist()
p = figure(x_range=countries)

p.vbar_stack(stackers=['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016'],
     x='Category', source=source,
     legend = ['01/01/2014 ', '01/01/2015 ', '01/01/2016 '],
     width=0.5, color=Spectral3)


p.title.text ='Average Number of Trades by Portfolio Size'
p.legend.location = 'top_right'

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Portfolio Size'
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None  #remove the x grid lines

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Average Number of Trades'

show(p)
```

Code 2 which does not work. Additional date added in.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral3

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['<£5000', '£100K to £250K'],
           '01/01/2014': [8,1],
           '01/01/2015': [8,2],
           '01/01/2016': [7,1],
           '01/01/2017': [9,4]})


grouped = df.groupby('Category')['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016', '01/01/2017'].mean().round(0)

source = ColumnDataSource(grouped)
countries = source.data['Category'].tolist()
p = figure(x_range=countries)

p.vbar_stack(stackers=['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016', '01/01/2017'],
     x='Category', source=source,
     legend = ['01/01/2014 ', '01/01/2015 ', '01/01/2016 ', '01/01/2017 '],
     width=0.5, color=Spectral3)


p.title.text ='Average Number of Trades by Portfolio Size'
p.legend.location = 'top_right'

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Portfolio Size'
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None  #remove the x grid lines

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Average Number of Trades'

show(p)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you increased the number of column in your dataframe but the color set Spectral3 has still only 3 colors.
The following code uses Spectral[11] so it is good for up to 11 dataframe columns. For more column / colors you would need to switch to other palette offering more colors (code tested for Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Category': ['<5000 EUR', '100K EUR to 250K EUR'],
                    '01/01/2014': [8, 1],
                    '01/01/2015': [8, 2],
                    '01/01/2016': [7, 1],
                    '01/01/2017': [9, 4] })

nmb_columns = (len(df.columns) - 1)
grouped = df.groupby('Category')['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016', '01/01/2017'].mean().round(0)

source = ColumnDataSource(grouped)
countries = source.data['Category'].tolist()
p = figure(x_range = countries)

p.vbar_stack(stackers = ['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016', '01/01/2017'],
     x = 'Category', source = source,
     legend = ['01/01/2014 ', '01/01/2015 ', '01/01/2016 ', '01/01/2017 '],
     width = 0.5, color = Spectral[11][:nmb_columns])

p.title.text = 'Average Number of Trades by Portfolio Size'
p.legend.location = 'top_left'
p.legend.click_policy = 'hide'

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Portfolio Size'
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None  # remove the x grid lines

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Average Number of Trades'

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]